# Loading dictionary stored as .npz fails

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, dictionary

l have a dictionary  store at once as one object using **np.savez** when l open it with **np.load** as follow :

l get the following :

```
my_dic=np.load('/home/values.npz')
my_dic.files
['scores']
```

However when l try :

```
my_dic['scores'] # len(my_dic['scores'])=1 but contains 3000 keys and 3000 values
```

it outputs all the keys and values as one object.

Is there any way to access the values and keys  ?

something like :

```
for k,values in my_dic['scores'].items():

    # do something
```

Thank you

Comment: If you used `savez` on a dictionary then it must have wrapped it in an object dtype array and saved that. `my_dict['scores'].item()` might extract the dictionary from that array.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you did:

```
In [80]: np.savez('test.npz', score={'a':1, 'b':2})

In [81]: d = np.load('test.npz')
In [83]: d.files
Out[83]: ['score']
In [84]: d['score']
Out[84]: array({'a': 1, 'b': 2}, dtype=object)
```

This is a 1 item array with a object dtype.  Extract that item with `item()`:

```
In [85]: d['score'].item()
Out[85]: {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

If instead I save the dictionary with `kwargs` syntax:

```
In [86]: np.savez('test.npz', **{'a':1, 'b':2})
In [87]: d = np.load('test.npz')
In [88]: d.files
Out[88]: ['a', 'b']
```

Now each dictionary key is a file in the archive:

```
In [89]: d['a']
Out[89]: array(1)
In [90]: d['b']
Out[90]: array(2)
```

Comment: I don't have the original data to save it again as you have mentionned. The only thing l have is my_dic=np.load('/home/values.npz') and from that l would like to get  my dictionnary keys and values

Comment: @hpaulji, d['score'].item() extract it at once . What if l would like to access it element by element  . something like d['score'].item()[0]

Answer (score 0):

Following the indications given by @hpalj, 
l did the following to solve the problem:

```
x=list(my_dic['scores'].item()) #allows me to get the keys 
keys=[]
values=[]
for i in np.arange(len(x))
  value=my_dic['scores'].item()[x[i]]
  values.append(value)
  keys.append(x[i])

final_dic=dict(zip(keys,values))
```